# Jackson return multiple(duplicate) feilds

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson2

JAVA POJO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Test1 {
    @JsonProperty("aBCFeexxxx")
    private double aBCFee;

}
```

TEST CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        t.setABCFee(10l);       
        System.out.println((new ObjectMapper()).writeValueAsString(t));
    }
```

OUTPUT:
`{"abcfee":10.0,"aBCFeexxxx":10.0}`

Why `acbfee` is returned in output ?
Expectation is we need to return only `aBCFeexxxx`

What am i doing wrong?

PS:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. This is the output that I got: `{"aBCFeexxxx":10.0}`

Comment: What is the Jackson version?

Comment: @michalk update question with versions... com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6

Answer (score 1):

Lombok and Jackson disagree on the naming convention for getters and setters of a property named `aBCFee`.

I don't use Lombok, so I had Eclipse create the getter/setter for me, and I got:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class Test1 {
    @JsonProperty("aBCFeexxxx")
    private double aBCFee;

    public double getaBCFee() {
        return this.aBCFee;
    }
    public void setaBCFee(double aBCFee) {
        this.aBCFee = aBCFee;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the setter method is named `setaBCFee`, not `setABCFee`. This code worked ok.

```json
{"aBCFeexxxx":10.0}
```

When I then renamed the methods to match what you had:

```
public double getABCFee() {
    return this.aBCFee;
}
public void setABCFee(double aBCFee) {
    this.aBCFee = aBCFee;
}
```

I got what you got:

```json
{"abcfee":10.0,"aBCFeexxxx":10.0}
```

As you can see, Jackson lowercased the first 4 characters, not just the first one, so as far as Jackson is concerned, the `abcfee` property defined by the getter/setter is different from the `aBCFee` property defined by the field, and hence you get two properties in the JSON text.

Java naming convention is for uppercase acronyms to be lowercased, e.g. "big HTML doc" should be named `bigHtmlDoc` as a field, and `setBigHtmlDoc` as a setter. I recommend you rename your field `abcFee`.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class Test1 {
    @JsonProperty("aBCFeexxxx")
    private double abcFee;

    public double getAbcFee() {
        return this.abcFee;
    }

    public void setAbcFee(double abcFee) {
        this.abcFee = abcFee;
    }
}
```

Jackson is happy with that:

```json
{"aBCFeexxxx":10.0}
```

Not having Lombok myself, I assume that it would name the getter/setter methods the same, so there is no longer any discrepancy.

Comment: "big HTML doc"   Great example